# RESTFul: Using POST to execute algorithms

Tags: algorithm, rest, post, get, restful-architecture

I'm designing a REST api, and I need an endpoint that executes an algorithm using the data sent by the client.

My first approach was to use a GET endpoint, because the algorithm is idempotent:

> Given an input with value "A" it always returns "B" and it never modifies anything in the server.

It would be great to model this using a GET endpoint, so we can use browser cache, bookmark and so on.

However I can't use a GET endpoint because the algorithm needs a very large JSON as input parameter and I don't want to send this parameter as URL parameter.

Seeing as I can't use GET, I've designed this endpoint using POST.

Now I have a doubt about HTTP status codes.

If the algorithm returns an empty result, I was going to send 404 status code that makes a lot of sense using a GET request.

But now, using a POST method, it seems a little bit strange to me:

```
POST /myAlgorithm
Response: 404 Not Found
```

It sounds like the user has written a wrong URL but the problem is the input parameter, that produces an empty response.

So my questions are:

Should I return an input list to deal with this case?

Does anybody knows how to design this kind of methods using a GET endpoint?

Comment: Why don't you just return 200 (OK) ? The algorithm was successfully executed and an empty result is a valid result.

Comment: Or [204 No Content](http://httpstatusdogs.com/204-no-content)

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about it and I agree with you @AakashM. I'm going to use 204 No Content. Can you post your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: If your processing is asynchronous, `202 Accepted` can be also used and `201 Created` if something is created.

Comment: 200 (Ok) or 204 (no error) looks ok to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an empty result and that's a legal value you should return 204, meaning that you have no error executing, but there was simply nothing to say.

Also, if the call is idempotent, POST is not the ideal way to go.
Both GET and PUT are assumed to be idempotent, but not POST (one of the many references [here](http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/idempotency/)).

Comment: Also there's for sure a design problem there. If you're calling an algorithm even when you're not violating any RESTful concept it's obviously you're designing a hybrid RPC-style REST and not a RESTful service. There's a technique but hardly doubt it applies to you when there are many parameters and it's encapsulating them into HTTP Headers, but it means you're passing parameters as expected not a whole object.

Comment: That's a good point. I'll give you a little more information: I'm coding an algorithm that given a graph (with vertex and edges) calculates some dependency nodes. I've modeled this algorithm as a resource called "blanket effect". I think it fits well in a REST API. The problem is that the algorithm needs a model as an input parameter, and it can contain a lot of vertex and edges. That's the reason I don't want to use GET method. But if you know a better approach please tell me

Answer (score 1):

I want to expand an answer and clarify a bit your question with some concepts.

Your question starts with "RESTFul. Using post to execute algorithms" which is a bit innacurate so we can review some concepts quickly.

REST is mainly and only related to VERBs to make it simply. Every webpage is REST
RESTful means you implement all the VERBs, webpages are not RESTful except for rare cases.

Most of the time RESTful goes hand-by-hand with Resource Oriented which is an architecture, RESTful is not an architecture, it's a set of design principles.

RESTful services work pretty well with ROA (resource-oriented architecture) because it's the natural way to do it. The main principle of ROA is the scope goes in the URI so a client can quickly understand looking at the request what's going on.

```
GET /users http/1.1
```

At a glance I clearly understand a client want the users list.

Also we have as a different architecture the classic RPC services. SOAP is one of them. A RPC service normally POST an action using an envelope (any kind) and receives a result into an envelope with a 200 ok answer and no more than that. This is of course a simplification of many other principles but it works to understand the concept.

A really good rule of thumb says if you heavily require POST you're not doing REST neither RESTful, or you're designing a RPC service or you have something clearly considered as **REST-RPC**.

In a RPC service the scoping and methods go into the envelope. Going back to your words:

> ... an endpoint that executes an algorithm using the data sent by the
>   client.

That's an obvious definition of RPC or at least REST-RPC

In this case you're not acting over a resource. There's not resource involved, you're executing an algorithm (process, hence, it's RPC). So, the idempotency here doesn't apply at all, there's no resource, there's not a necessity of using GET.
Again, considering you need to POST your data because it's big, and this data cannot be considered scope (for example, a scope in Google is the set of parameters you pass to the engine), it cannot use any classic REST technique, basically because you're doing RPC calls.

My answer is you don't need to think in your service in terms of GET or RESTful, consider it a REST-RPC hybrid as it was designed. It means you POST an envelope (your data) and get 200 ok with an envelope as an answer (in your case, the result of the operation.

That would be the correct way to manage it.

Comment: Well, I don't agree with you in some points. You're right in that the key concept of REST is resource, but a resource is anything we expose to the web, from a document of video clip to a business process or device, even an algorithm result. You can model an algorithm output as a resource and creates a JSON representation of it. The magic consist of extract the useful information of those resources and make this information accesible on the web. With this technique, any developer can publish almost any physical resource to the Web.

Comment: Moreover, I don't want to use REST because it's cool or popular, but because I want to use the capabilities of the communication protocol: verbs and status codes to coordinate interactions. So each resource exposed on my API by these services responds to some HTTP verbs in order to manipulate its resource.

Comment: I agree with you in that an algorithm looks like a RPC endpoint, but I think it can be designed as a resource, and that's what I'm trying to do

Comment: Based on the recommendations of the experts that I like to follow, a resource is an algorithm but in your case it looks like a regular RPC call. As I mentioned the rule of thumb is always you need to POST because it's not possible to scope it and that is not REST. In REST you could pass the scope in the URI or maximum in the HTTP headers, if you pass an object that's not RESTful for sure.

Comment: I've never said you use REST because it's popular. Not my words. But I did design a lot of REST services and refined my view of how to build them reading a lot and watching tons of experts. It doesn't make me an expert but clear rules help to design better. In my opinion (not saying it's the perfect opinion) it does look clearly as a REST-RPC hybrid.

Comment: Agreed: clear rules help to design better. First of all, I'd like to thank you for your response. You're the only one who has gave me a full detailed answer. I also think my approach has to do more with RPC than REST. I don't like the use of POST in this situation at all. Maybe it could be better to design a resource "Model" that has an attribute "Blanket Effect". In that situation I could create the model (using POST) and receive a craated model with its blanketEffect attribute or even I could query the Blanket effect using GET /models/{id}/BlanketEffect. What do you think?

Comment: Well, that's exactly REST :) Or more accurate, that's REST Resource Oriented. As I said, REST is more about the verbs and ROA about modeling using resources (algorithms are resources too but they have to behave as a resource). In my opinion there's a huge difference between a service open to the world (public) and a private one. Some public APIs don't care too much about being RESTful ROA to avoid many calls for example but that's a different discussion.